# Ath10k vht IBSS

Tags: wireless, 18.04, adhoc

I'm trying to build a VHT Ad Hoc network with wpa_supplicant. I'm using wpa_supplicant v2.8 and QCA9882 wireless card with ath10k driver. I tried the method given by https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/6576561/ and there are still some bugs. Command ' iw list' returns

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 16
    max scan IEs length: 195 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
...
...
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x19ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x338001b2):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            RX antenna pattern consistency
            TX antenna pattern consistency
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed, P2P-client } <= 8, #{ P2P-GO } <= 3, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 7,
           total <= 8, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports VHT-IBSS.
```

The configure file of wpa_supplicant looks like:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1
network={
    ssid="Myssid"
    mode=1
    frequency=5180
    proto=WPA
    key_mgmt=WPA-NONE
    pairwise=NONE
    group=TKIP
    psk="12345678"
}
```

When I ran wpa_supplicant, it returns as below. I omitted some repetitive scan results in order to satisfy the body length requirement.

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf -d
wpa_supplicant v2.8
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf' driver 'nl80211' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf'
ctrl_interface='/run/wpa_supplicant'
ap_scan=1
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='Myssid'
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 7 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x557cd17af0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0104
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0409506f9a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0a0b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=1101
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=1102
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0505
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd17af0 match=0500
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=7 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
Add interface wlan0 to a new radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467[DISABLED] 2472[DISABLED] 2484[DISABLED][NO_IR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260[RADAR] 5280[RADAR] 5300[RADAR] 5320[RADAR] 5500[RADAR] 5520[RADAR] 5540[RADAR] 5560[RADAR] 5580[RADAR] 5600[RADAR] 5620[RADAR] 5640[RADAR] 5660[RADAR] 5680[RADAR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467[DISABLED] 2472[DISABLED] 2484[DISABLED][NO_IR]
wlan0: Own MAC address: 00:03:07:12:34:56
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
wlan0: Setting scan request: 0.100000 sec
wlan0: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: 8523cdd3-402f-538a-a41c-400dd0cd9a57
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
MBO: Update non-preferred channels, non_pref_chan=N/A
wlan0: Added interface wlan0
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=7 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
nl80211: New P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0 (0x5) created
Initializing interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf' driver 'nl80211' ctrl_interface '/run/wpa_supplicant' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant-adhoc.conf'
ctrl_interface='/run/wpa_supplicant'
ap_scan=1
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='Myssid'
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface p2p-dev-wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 0 iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 0 to mode 10: -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x557cd43cd0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557cd43cd0 match=0104
... ...
nl80211: Use (wlan0) to initialize P2P Device rfkill
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Start P2P Device p2p-dev-wlan0 (0x5): Success
Add interface p2p-dev-wlan0 to existing radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467[DISABLED] 2472[DISABLED] 2484[DISABLED][NO_IR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260[RADAR] 5280[RADAR] 5300[RADAR] 5320[RADAR] 5500[RADAR] 5520[RADAR] 5540[RADAR] 5560[RADAR] 5580[RADAR] 5600[RADAR] 5620[RADAR] 5640[RADAR] 5660[RADAR] 5680[RADAR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467[DISABLED] 2472[DISABLED] 2484[DISABLED][NO_IR]
p2p-dev-wlan0: Own MAC address: 00:03:07:12:34:56
p2p-dev-wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
p2p-dev-wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> INACTIVE
p2p-dev-wlan0: WPS: UUID from the first interface: 8523cdd3-402f-538a-a41c-400dd0cd9a57
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
Using existing control interface directory.
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=11): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 95 99 9d a1
P2P: Add operating class 125
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=5): 95 99 9d a1 a5
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 95 9d
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Own listen channel: 81:1
P2P: Random operating channel: 81:11
P2P: initialized
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 124:149,153,157,161 125:149,153,157,161,165 126:149,157 127:153,161 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
MBO: Update non-preferred channels, non_pref_chan=N/A
p2p-dev-wlan0: Added interface p2p-dev-wlan0
p2p-dev-wlan0: State: INACTIVE -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set p2p-dev-wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=0 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
p2p-dev-wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 1)
p2p-dev-wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=11): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 95 99 9d a1
P2P: Add operating class 125
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=5): 95 99 9d a1 a5
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 95 9d
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Update channel list
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 124:149,153,157,161 125:149,153,157,161,165 126:149,157 127:153,161 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=7 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=7 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=1 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 1)
wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=11): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 95 99 9d a1
P2P: Add operating class 125
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=5): 95 99 9d a1 a5
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 95 9d
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Update channel list
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 124:149,153,157,161 125:149,153,157,161,165 126:149,157 127:153,161 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
wlan0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
WPS: Building WPS IE for Probe Request
WPS:  * Version (hardcoded 0x10)
WPS:  * Request Type
WPS:  * Config Methods (3108)
WPS:  * UUID-E
WPS:  * Primary Device Type
WPS:  * RF Bands (3)
WPS:  * Association State
WPS:  * Configuration Error (0)
WPS:  * Device Password ID (0)
WPS:  * Manufacturer
WPS:  * Model Name
WPS:  * Model Number
WPS:  * Device Name
WPS:  * Version2 (0x20)
P2P: * P2P IE header
P2P: * Capability dev=25 group=00
P2P: * Listen Channel: Regulatory Class 81 Channel 1
wlan0: Add radio work 'scan'@0x557cd4a6a0
wlan0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
wlan0: Starting radio work 'scan'@0x557cd4a6a0 after 0.000044 second wait
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 10 seconds
nl80211: Ignored event (cmd=33) for foreign interface (ifindex 7 wdev 0x0)
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (46) received
wlan0: Own scan request started a scan in 0.000155 seconds
EAPOL: disable timer tick
EAPOL: disable timer tick
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=7 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Ignored event (cmd=34) for foreign interface (ifindex 7 wdev 0x0)
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan probed for SSID ''
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700 5720 5745 5765 5785 5805 5825
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
wlan0: Scan completed in 3.403952 seconds
nl80211: Received scan results (8 BSSes)
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 1
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID 20:6b:e7:1e:cf:82 SSID 'LAB223_5G' freq 5745
... ...
BSS: last_scan_res_used=8/32
wlan0: New scan results available (own=1 ext=0)
wlan0: Radio work 'scan'@0x557cd4a6a0 done in 3.406177 seconds
wlan0: radio_work_free('scan'@0x557cd4a6a0): num_active_works --> 0
wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 0
wlan0: 0: 20:6b:e7:1e:cf:82 ssid='LAB223_5G' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x511 level=-35 freq=5745 
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch
......
wlan0: No suitable network found
wlan0: Setup a new network
wlan0: No ongoing scan/p2p-scan found to abort
wlan0: Add radio work 'connect'@0x557cd4a6a0
wlan0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
p2p-dev-wlan0: Updating scan results from sibling
nl80211: Received scan results (8 BSSes)
p2p-dev-wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 1
p2p-dev-wlan0: BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID 20:6b:e7:1e:cf:82 SSID 'LAB223_5G' freq 5745
... ...
BSS: last_scan_res_used=8/32
p2p-dev-wlan0: New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
wlan0: Starting radio work 'connect'@0x557cd4a6a0 after 0.000986 second wait
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'Myssid'
wlan0: Cancelling scan request
wlan0: WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
wlan0: WPA: No WPA/RSN IE available from association info
wlan0: WPA: Set cipher suites based on configuration
wlan0: WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 8 pairwise 1 key_mgmt 16 proto 1
wlan0: WPA: Selected mgmt group cipher 32
wlan0: WPA: clearing AP WPA IE
wlan0: WPA: clearing AP RSN IE
wlan0: WPA: AP group 0x8 network profile group 0x8; available group 0x8
wlan0: WPA: using GTK TKIP
wlan0: WPA: AP pairwise 0x1 network profile pairwise 0x1; available pairwise 0x1
wlan0: WPA: using PTK NONE
wlan0: WPA: AP key_mgmt 0x10 network profile key_mgmt 0x10; available key_mgmt 0x10
wlan0: WPA: using KEY_MGMT WPA-NONE
wlan0: WPA: AP mgmt_group_cipher 0x20 network profile mgmt_group_cipher 0x0; available mgmt_group_cipher 0x0
wlan0: WPA: not using MGMT group cipher
WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 00 01 00 00 50 f2 00
WPA: No current PMKSA - clear PMK
wlan0: Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=7 (wlan0) alg=2 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=1 seq_len=6 key_len=32
nl80211: KEY_DATA - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
nl80211: KEY_SEQ - hexdump(len=6): 00 00 00 00 00 00
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-67 Link has been severed)
wlan0: State: SCANNING -> ASSOCIATING
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=7 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 1)
wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=11): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 95 99 9d a1
P2P: Add operating class 125
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=5): 95 99 9d a1 a5
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 95 9d
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Update channel list
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 124:149,153,157,161 125:149,153,157,161,165 126:149,157 127:153,161 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
nl80211: Received scan results (8 BSSes)
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 2
IBSS/mesh: setup freq channel 36, sec_channel_offset 1
IBSS: VHT setup freq cf1 5210, cf2 0, bw 80
wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 1)
wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
nl80211: Join IBSS (ifindex=7)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 7 iftype 1 (ADHOC)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 7 to mode 1: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down
nl80211: Set freq 5180 (ht_enabled=1, vht_enabled=1, bandwidth=80 MHz, cf1=5210 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
  * freq=5180
  * vht_enabled=1
  * ht_enabled=1
  * bandwidth=80
  * channel_width=3
  * center_freq1=5210
  * center_freq2=0
nl80211: Failed to set channel (freq=5180): -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Failed to set frequency on interface
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 7 iftype 1 (ADHOC)
nl80211: Mode change succeeded while interface is down
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Device or resource busy
nl80211: Failed to set interface up after switching mode
nl80211: Interface mode change to 1 from 1 failed
nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Radio work 'connect'@0x557cd4a6a0 done in 0.005600 seconds
wlan0: radio_work_free('connect'@0x557cd4a6a0): num_active_works --> 0
Added BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 into blacklist
wlan0: Blacklist count 1 --> request scan in 100 ms
wlan0: Setting scan request: 0.100000 sec
wlan0: State: ASSOCIATING -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=7 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 1)
wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=11): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 95 99 9d a1
P2P: Add operating class 125
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=5): 95 99 9d a1 a5
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 95 9d
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Update channel list
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 124:149,153,157,161 125:149,153,157,161,165 126:149,157 127:153,161 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
```

I don't know how to deal with this problem, any hints I could follow to make it working?
My platform is NVIDIA Jetson Xavier, with Ubuntu 18.04 and linux kernel v4.9.140.

Comment: Did you put the interface in ad-hoc mode first; i.e. `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` and then: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc` and finally: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I tried your advice, but the previous problem became even worse. It returned in the beginning: Failed to set interface 7 to mode 2: -16(Device or resource busy), and the previous problem still exists. And I found that the interface was set in master mode after I terminated the wpa_supplicant command. It seemed that wpa_supplicant tried to set the interface in master mode before setting it to ad-hoc mode?